# Mountain bike Yazoo Fsv 3.6n front derailleur shifter is not shifting under the 2nd gear

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, shifting, derailleur-front

My Yazoo FSV 3.6N MTB front derailleur is not shifting under the 2nd gear. When I try to shift down it doesn't go to 1st gear, it stays between 1st and 2nd. I'd  leave a video here but I can't.

Comment: Have you tried one of the online instruction videos for front-derailleur-setup? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNG7g83lI-s

Comment: If you have exposed inner cable at the downtube or top tube, try pulling on it to see if the gear changes.  That tests whether its possible to shift at all, and rules out the shifter on the bars.